# UI-Router state controller: Named vs Inline Function

Tags: angular-ui-router

I am attempting to have  DRY states with UI-Router. I have a page service `AlchemyPage` which fetches a page through the API using `$http.get`

This works perfectly when I use it with an inline controller:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  controller: function($stateParams, $scope, AlchemyPage) {
    AlchemyPage.load($stateParams, $scope);
  }
});

$stateProvider.state('organization', {
  url: '/package-organization/:page',
  templateUrl: 'alchemy/page.html',
  controller: function($stateParams, $scope, AlchemyPage) {
    $scope.org = true;
    AlchemyPage.load($stateParams, $scope);
  }
});
```

I attempted to get rid of repetition and created a controller:

```
angular.module('App').controller('MainPageCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  '$stateParams',
  'isOrganization',
  'AlchemyPage',
  function($scope,
  $stateParams,
  isOrganization,
  AlchemyPage) {
    $scope.org = isOrganization;
    AlchemyPage.load($stateParams,$scope);
  }
]);
```

However, when I implemented as below, the controller does not get called.

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'alchemy/home.html',
  controller: 'MainPageCtrl',
  resolve: {
    isOrganization: 'false'
  }
});
$stateProvider.state('organization', {
  url: '/package-organization/:page',
  templateUrl: 'alchemy/page.html',
  controller: 'MainPageCtrl',
  resolve: {
    isOrganization: 'true'
  }
});
```

Using AngularJS v.1.6.4

### Using UI-Router v.0.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using `params` instead of `resolve`

Modified 'home' state:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'alchemy/home.html',
  controller: 'MainPageCtrl'
});
```

The below `resolve` object no longer needed in either state due to changing logic in `AlchemyPage` resource:

```
resolve: {
    isOrganization: 'false'
  }
```

Revised `state` for organization:

```
$stateProvider.state('organization', {
  url: '/package-organization/:page',
  templateUrl: 'alchemy/page.html',
  controller: 'MainPageCtrl',
  params: {
    topic: 'organization'
  }
});
```

You can see in the above that the flag is now set for organization by passing in

```
params: {
  topic: 'organization'
}
```

So here is the cleaned up controller:

```
App.controller('MainPagedCtrl', [
  '$stateParams',
  '$scope',
  'AlchemyPage',
  function($stateParams,
  $scope,
  AlchemyPage) {
    AlchemyPage.load($stateParams,
  $scope);
  }
]);
```

With the above corrections, the named controller works properly. Resolve does work as expected, I was just using it improperly.